# How to style ::before or ::after pseudo elements to be between items that are in more then one line?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I have this problem I have ul list (navigation) and I want to put bullet between and make then in one line, this works but when I resize the window (same on mobile) I've got two lines and then first item in next line have bullet between, is it possible to get rid of it with some tricks or is manual breakpoints and nth-child the only option?

```css
ul {
   width: 200px;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   list-style: none;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}
ul li {
  display: inline;
}
ul li + li::before {
  content: "•";
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem</li>
  <li>Ipsum</li>
  <li>Dolor</li>
  <li>Sit</li>
  <li>Amet</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You mean in your example you wish to `Sit` not have bullet?

Comment: @Justinas yes and the width can change so it should not show bullet on first item in next lines.

Comment: I don't think CSS can make it. But you can always use media queries for that to "predict" where element will be

Comment: @Justinas that's want I've expected but was not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider `:after` pseudo element then hide it for the last element and the last element for each row. This remain a *hacky* approximation, it may not work in all the cases.

```css
ul {
   width: 200px;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   list-style: none;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   position:relative;
}
ul li {
  /*display: inline; no needed*/ 
}
ul li:not(:last-child)::after {
  content: "•";
  /*display: inline; no needed*/
  margin: 0 10px;
}
ul li:last-child {
  margin-right:10px;
}

ul:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:20px;
  background:#fff;
}
```

```html
<ul style="width:100%">
  <li>Lorem</li>
  <li>Ipsum</li>
  <li>Dolor</li>
  <li>Sit</li>
  <li>Amet</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Lorem</li>
  <li>Ipsum</li>
  <li>Dolor</li>
  <li>Sit</li>
  <li>Amet</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The problem with your solution is that the ul is not centered, but using it I came up with better one, using overflow on container wrapper.

Comment: @jcubic we can adjust centring and other things but as I said it remain a hacky way .. so you need to tweak it specifically to your needs.

Comment: Yes, the other problem is that it will only work if the line have full width if it's shorter the bullet will be shown. So you still will need few media queries to make this work. But thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @TemaniAfif solution but without dummy hiding after pseudo selector on ul and instead using position to make ul overflow the container.

```css
ul {
   width: 200px;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   list-style: none;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   position:relative;
   left: 20px;
}
ul li {
  /*display: inline; no needed*/ 
}
.wrapper {
  margin-left: -20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
} 
ul li:not(:last-child)::after {
  content: "•";
  /*display: inline; no needed*/
  margin: 0 10px;
}
ul li:last-child {
  margin-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<ul style="width:100%">
  <li>Lorem</li>
  <li>Ipsum</li>
  <li>Dolor</li>
  <li>Sit</li>
  <li>Amet</li>
</ul>
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Ipsum</li>
    <li>Dolor</li>
    <li>Sit</li>
    <li>Amet</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
ul {
   width: 200px;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   list-style: none;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}
ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin-left:-1em;
  margin-right:1em;
  z-index:1;
}
/* hide stray bullet with ul::before */
ul::before {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 3em;
  background: white;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}

ul li + li::before {
  content: "•";
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem</li>
  <li>Ipsum</li>
  <li>Dolor</li>
  <li>Sit</li>
  <li>Amet</li>
</ul>
```